# A way for client to trigger Ansible Playbook?

Tags: automation, ansible

My task is to automate CentOS installs, including a suite of proprietary software, onto bare metal machines. I've set up a PXE boot server which automates initial install from a Kickstart file and the rest gets passed to an Ansible Playbook.

I've solved all of the above, except I have to be in the server to start the Playbook. I haven't found a good way for the Playbook to start at the request of the client (or perhaps the server-side PXE process can hand it off somehow?), in the hopes that I can cut myself out of the install process.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to execute it automatically in a scheduled way or execute it manually but without having to login into the server (via http for example) ?

Comment: @med.b I'm looking for it to execute automatically following the Kickstart file portion of a PXE network install, with the PXE install being started by a user.

Comment: You want the playbook to execute on the server? Or on the client? Because if the answer is "on the client" then you may want to investigate [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html).

Comment: @larsks I was thinking about executing on the server, but against the client. This is interesting, thank you. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I would expand on my comment a little bit.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, there are a few options you could consider.

### Use ansible-pull

The `ansible-pull` cli fetches a `git` repository from a remote server and then locally executes `ansible-playbook playbook.yml` in the top level of that repository.

This means you can drop something like this into your Kickstart `%post` script:

```
ansible-pull -U https://server.example.com/playbooks/client-configuration
```

This is a great solution if your playbook only requires running tasks on the client.

### Trigger a playbook run on the server

If your playbook really needs to execute on the server, you could set up a simple web server that would allow clients to trigger the playbook run.  In this case, you would embed `curl` command or similar into your Kickstart `%post` script:

```
curl https://my.server.com/trigger-playbook
```

The `trigger-playbook` service would take care of triggering a playbook run targeting the appropriate client. This would require you to implement the service yourself (or use something like [webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) to handle that task for you).

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll try option #2 first and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted just because it would totally work. However, just for posterity, I'll add that to solve the problem myself I simply provided a network share and had the client drop request files for the server to act upon.